# Can a Sorcerer use Flexible Casting to create more spell slots than is listed on the Sorcerer table?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, spell-slots

A Sorcerer can create spell slots by expending sorcery points with the Flexible Casting feature.

In the rules, is there any point where it states that you can't have more spell slots than what the table shows?

One method that could potentially allow them to gain more slots than the table lists is by using a particular [Sorcerer/Warlock build](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78918/does-this-character-concept-involving-never-taking-a-long-rest-and-converting-sp). The core being that they can take short rests over and over again and, using flexible casting, turn warlock slots into sorcery points and then into normal slots.

Is this supported by the rules?

Does the Sorcerer table show the maximum slots that a sorcerer can have or could they go above that?

Can the Sorcerer create spell slots in levels they don't currently have?

Comment: @Deceptecium if you edit that question to only be about slots and the table, it might not be a duplicate, but it would be very close.

Comment: Well whatever I need to do because the answers on the link primarily go over resting and I'm not worried about the resting I am worried specifically about spell casting rules.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if flexible casting overrides the general rule of not having spell slots larger than what your level is capable and not having more spell slots than what your table shows. Even though flexible casting doesn't specifically say it overrides it and thus it wouldn't. But that isn't a good enough answer so I need the actual text

Comment: @Deceptecium I've edited your text into what I think is the most likely form to not be a duplicate. Is it still asking what you intended?

Comment: Thanks I'm not meaning to seem upset just got woke up very early with spam messages about this and am grumpy XD so after looking over phb myself for a few hours decided to make a post. Because I couldn't find anything in the spell casting rules saying that the max slots the table shows is the max possible. It gives a grooves explanation but that seems more the magic than anything. It just doesn't make sense to me that a 7th level sorc can potentially have more 5th slots than a 20th level wizard

Comment: Reopened based on [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/1204). This is a fairly straightforward question, and if we're going to have multiple questions about this, let's at least have a fairly simple straightforward case where we handle it.

Comment: Thanks should I put the meta post in the question or dont worry about it?

Comment: Can you confirm first that the edit still reflects what you want to ask? I basically rewrote it from scratch and so I want to be sure I haven't diverged from what you want.

Comment: Related: [How does "Flexible Casting" give more spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57801/41726)

Comment: Just looked at it and the and one of the answers could work but it doesnt seem to go over rules of spell casting in a sourced way and their is a comment under it having to do with the level 7 not having 5th slots but being able to make them issue that doesn't get addressed their either.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about digging through that other question too much. We ought to give you a straightforward answer here to your straightforward question rather than leaving you needing to sift through that whole thing. This is reopened now so we can give you that.

Comment: Mkies thank you, I am still currently looking to see if I can amswer it as Well

Comment: @DavidCoffron Is the difference between your related and this just the specific bit on creating more? Because yours very much seems identical.

Comment: @NautArch I thought that too at first but the meta on the other question encompassing (but including other aspects to) this one seems to disagree.

Answer (score 10):

### This works

There are no general rules limiting the number of spell slots. [The Spellcasting rules only say](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellSlots):

> Thus, each spellcasting class's description... includes a table showing how many spell slots of each spell level a character can use at each character level.

This can't be a hard limit on usable spell slots, as you can gain additional spell slots with features such as the Boon of High Magic from the Dungeon Master's Guide:

> You gain one 9th-level spell slot, provided that you already have one.

The wizard's Arcane Recovery says (**emphasis** mine)

> Once per day when you finish a short rest, you can choose **expended spell slots to recover.**

These must be expended slots, but Flexible Casting says:

> You can transform unexpended sorcery points into one spell slot as a bonus action on your turn... **creating a spell slot** of a given level. **You can create** spell slots...
>
> Any spell slot **you create**...

All the references to creating slots shows that these slots need not be expended, and since there is no hard limit on the number of spell slots a character can have, a sorcerer can stack up additional spell slots beyond their level's baseline. This includes spell slots of a level beyond those usually available to a spellcaster.

Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer, supports this interpretation [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/972239870499291136?s=20):

> Using Flexible Casting, a sorcerer can convert sorcery points into spell slots. The number of sorcery points you have is the only limit on the number of slots you can create in this way. (Remember that the slots go away when you finish a long rest.)

Comment: What about slots they aren't capable of using such as the 7th level sorc and 5th level slots

Comment: @Deceptecium again, i see no limit. Appended a clarifying sentence.

Comment: FYI Crawford has [a lot to say](https://twitter.com/search?q=flexible%20casting%20from%3AJeremyECrawford&src=typd) on this matter. I'm pretty sure OP wants RAW and thus it might not be the most helpful but he does explicitly agree with you.

Comment: Thank you for providing this information, it’s good to have this confirmed here and with Jeremy. I just worked it out myself that with my level 4 warlock / level 8 sorcerer, My 4-hour trancing Elf can create 2 x 5th level slots every time the rest of the team have their normal 8 hour long rest, by having my 4 hour trance, and then 4 short rests with flexible casting conversions between short rests. This is superb. 2 extra 25hp Armor of Agathys shields, or a free 25hp Armor of Agathys and and a free 20hp Aid. +45hp overall. For nothing. Nice. :)